# $p$-subgroup of Sylow and Normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime that divides $|G|$, and $P$ a $p$-subgroup of Sylow of $G$. Show that $P$ is the unique $p$-subgroup of Sylow that is in $N_G(P)$.

I tried this by assuming there is another $p$-subgroup of Sylow called $Q$. So by the second Sylow's theorem, $Pg=gQ$; but I don't see something to justify that $P=Q$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A Sylow subgroup is unique iff it is normal, since they are all conjugate by Sylow.  But the Sylow subgroup will be normal in its normalizer, plus it will be a Sylow subgroup again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Q$ is another $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_G(P)$ then indeed by the Sylow theorems we have $Q=gPg^{-1}$ for some $g\in N_G(P)$. But $P$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(P)$, and so $gPg^{-1}=P$.

Comment: Oh that's right! I forgot that a subgroup is normal under his normalizer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  By one of Sylow's theorems, all the Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

$\;\;\;\;\;$ Firstly, note that if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ then $P$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of any $G$ subgroup containing $P$.

$\;\;\;\;\;$ By definition, $P$ is a normal subgroup of its $\it{normalizer}$ $$\mathcal N(P):=\{g\in G:gP=Pg\}=\{g\in G:P=gPg^{-1}\}$$ Equivalently, $P$ itself is the only conjugate of $P$ in $\mathcal N(P)$. Sylow gaurantees that the $\mathcal N(P)$ Sylow subgroups are conjugates and thus $P$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\mathcal N(P)$.